# How do I add jquery animation to the pagination in Matrix?

Tags: add-on, matrix, jquery

How do I add jquery animation to the pagination in Matrix? I got help from P&T Support and they showed me how to add pagination to Matrix in Expression Engine. I was wondering how to add jquery animation/fade/slide to the Matrix row changes?

Comment: Welcome! Please consider showing some more effort in your question. What have you tried? What stumbling blocks are you hitting? Show your work!

Answer (score 1):

If you want animation for the pagination, you should use jQuery. Here are **[10 jQuery Pagination Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/)** to look at.